# calling concurrently Graphics.Draw and new Bitmap from memory in thread take long time

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing

Example1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        pro = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Producer));
        con = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Consumer));
    }
    private AutoResetEvent m_DataAvailableEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Queue<Bitmap> queue = new Queue<Bitmap>();
    Thread pro;
    Thread con;

    public void Producer()
    {
        MemoryStream[] ms = new MemoryStream[3];
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("image" + (y + 1) + ".JPG");
            BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(reader.BaseStream);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.BaseStream.Length];
            breader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ms[y] = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        }
        while (true)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms[x]);
                queue.Enqueue(bmp);

                m_DataAvailableEvent.Set();
                Thread.Sleep(6);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Consumer()
    {
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        while (true)
        {
            m_DataAvailableEvent.WaitOne();
            Bitmap bmp = queue.Dequeue();
            if (bmp != null)
            {
                //  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
                bmp.Dispose();

            }
        }

    }
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Start();
        pro.Start();

    }
}
```

When creating bitmap and drawing to picture box are in seperate thread
then `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms[x])` takes 45.591 millisecond
and   `g.DrawImage(bmp,new Point(0,0))`  takes 41.430 milisecond.

When I make a bitmap from memoryStream and draw it to picture box in one thread then
`Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms[x])` takes 29.619 and `g.DrawImage(bmp,new Point(0,0))` takes 35.540.

The code is for Example 2 is

```
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    pro = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Producer));
    con = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Consumer));
}

private AutoResetEvent m_DataAvailableEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Queue<MemoryStream> queue = new Queue<MemoryStream>();
Thread pro;
Thread con;

public void Producer()
{
    MemoryStream[] ms = new MemoryStream[3];
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("image" + (y + 1) + ".JPG");
        BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(reader.BaseStream);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.BaseStream.Length];
        breader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ms[y] = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            // Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms[x]);
            queue.Enqueue(ms[x]);

            m_DataAvailableEvent.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(6);
        }
    }
}

public void Consumer()
{
    Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    while (true)
    {
        m_DataAvailableEvent.WaitOne();
        //Bitmap bmp = queue.Dequeue();
        MemoryStream ms = queue.Dequeue();
        if (ms != null)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
            g.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
            bmp.Dispose();

        }
    }

}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con.Start();
    pro.Start();

}
```

Why does it take more time to draw and create a bitmap in seperate thread and how to reduce the time when processing in seperate thread ? I am using ANTS performance profiler 4.3

Comment: IMHO, 3 images aren't enough to make judgement on performance. Difference in execution times here can be caused by multiple factors. I'd recommend you to make more measures.

OFF TOPIC: The code you've wrote here is not well-parallelized: (1) you read ALL images before passing it to consumer - it's better to load and pass them one by one; (2) your implementation of Prod/Cons is broken which can be seen by the appearance of Thread.Sleep call. Rewrite it to using semaphores (see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).
You also should dispose Graphics object you create.

Answer (score 0):

All UI operations should take place on the same thread. In fact if you want your system to be stable they must all take place on the same thread. I guess that what you're seeing with the slower performance on the multithreaded code is evidence of that instability.

By all means load the images in separate threads, but update the UI in the main thread.

If you search for questions tagged [multithreading] [c#] here on Stack Overflow you'll see many other questions along the same lines as yours.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660867/setting-form-owner-to-a-form-from-a-different-thread) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638991/thread-for-windows-form) for example.